# How to circumvent WAN cap of 100mbps on router and get full bandwidth on my PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a router which has a WAN port supporting 100mbps. I have a 200mbps connection but am getting only 100mbps when I use a LAN connection from the router. I need the router so that we can use it for wireless devices but I use a wired connection.

I really need the other 100mbps but I don't know what to do. Can I use a splitter  and split the 200mbps connection so that I get a 200MBps on my PC and a 100 MBps input to my router?

Answer (score 6):

In short, you cannot just connect two devices to one incoming line.

You will need a router capable of handling the speeds your provider gives you. You will have to check with them as to the precise spec they use [& also what they plan to use in future, so you don't get caught out with an out of date device in only a year or two.]